# Angularjs Select doesn't work in a modal window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hello,
I'm using angularJs and bootstrap to develop a web application. 
I have a problem when I use a select in a modal window. 
Here is the link to a plunker file which work. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/mcl2BMQhWRvRffvbw2nX?p=preview 

It's just to give you an idea of my problem. I can't put the real code because it's for a confidencial university project. And I couldn't make in plunker a similar code which didn't works.

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ["item1","item2","item3"];
  
  $scope.open = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
            items: function() {
              return $scope.items;
            }
          }
    });
  };
  
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
  $scope.items = items;
  
  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.items);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
  
};
```

```html
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];

  $scope.open = function() {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function() {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
  };

};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
  $scope.items = items;

  $scope.ok = function() {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.items);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };

};
```

So my problem is the following : in the select tag (in the view) I can see all the options but I can't select them. 
I tried to put a "." in my ng-model reference and I tried to use the parent scope. (I think I'm good with the scope, I read all the documentation about it, I read several topics on forums and I tried a lot of things). 
So, I'm pretty sure that the problem doesn't come directly from the scope. (Moreover, I don't want the parent scope to be triggered so it should works in the normal way). 
The thing is, ng-options can't work without ng-model in a `<select>`. So I guess that my `$scope.selectedItem` is created somewhere. But after that the selection is blocked and I can't select anything. 
If I put a default value in the controller for my `$scope.selectedItem`, the select tag is updated and the default value appear to be selected. But I still can't select anything else.

Do you have an idea from where it can come from ?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english :)

Comment: What do you mean by **can't select anything**? is the select blocked or it just won't accept your changes?

Comment: The select is blocked. I can see the different options but when I select one by clicking, nothing happen.

Comment: I found something really weird. I have a friend which is working with firefox (like me). On his computer he can use the select in a normal way. He can chose any value as he wants with exactly the same code. We have the same version of firefox. The only thing different is the operating system. He uses windows 8 and I'm using ubuntu 14.04. Is it possible that the problem comes from that ?

Comment: This could be possible as the browser will use different native libraries on each platform. 
Did you check the HTML code with firebug (or what is the current debugging tool in firefox). If you inspect your **dropdown** will it be selected in the firebug or might there be an invisible `div` overlay?

Comment: There is no overlay div. And it's not selected in the firebug. For the same code (exept the `ng-model`) for a `select` in two different window (one modal the other not), I have exactly the same code in the firebug. I can select whatever I want in the normal window, but the `select` doesn't work in the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. With bootstrap, we can create modal windows without declaring anything in the javascript file. For that, we must include the modal window in the html file which use it.
Here is an example which show a solution (it's not the same example than above) : 
This code open the modal :

```
<div ng-include="getItemTemplate('modalVariables')"></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-section" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#variablesModal">Variables</button>
```

And in the modal we have :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="variablesModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
<!-- content of the modal window here -->
</div>
```

With this code a select inside the modal is correctly working for me. But I still don't know why it wasn't working before.